# how to parse html  in iphone app

Tags: html, objective-c, xml

i am doing an iphone app,

there are sample project in this web
 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

how to change this sample project to get " A few years ago " in this web code:(http://www.ted.com/talks/matt_cutts_try_something_new_for_30_days.html)

???

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find any sense in your question. What's `http:view-source`? And what exactly do you want to do with the `Morgan Spurlock` string?

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you're doing, but I don't recommend trying to parse HTML with an XML parser.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Hpple](https://github.com/shsteven/hpple), it's a nice HTML parser using XPath queries, which are really easy to learn.